# DMAIC - Define, Measure, Analyse, Improve, Control in the DevOps world?

Tags: methodology, itil

Six Sigma's [DMAIC](https://www.isixsigma.com/methodology/dmaic-methodology/what-dmaic/) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMAIC)) has been there before continuous procedures, so I think more or less these concepts have been nourishing [itil](/questions/tagged/itil), then CI/CD and now DevOps as well.

Still I am not sure whether we have an established data model for example to allow DMAIC across many iterations.

Question: do you know of examples of practices/ aligning DMAIC with DevOps (at the measure side, first of all)? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, DMAIC makes sense. If processes like CD need to be improved it is important to have a baseline. Therefore the **M**easure step is useful. The team investigates the status of process X, e.g. CD by documenting the current status.